# Unexpected syntax error: unexpected number

Tags: javascript, math, syntax-error

I am trying to make a function the creates a random number with decimals, but I have a syntax error using `1e+decimalPlaces`.

The function is:

```
_$.randomNumberWithDecimals = function(min, max, decimals) {
    var random = Math.random();
    random = random * 1e+decimals;
};
```

and the error is on:

```
random = random * 1e+decimals;
```

the error my editor gives me is:
`Unexpected 1.` The error I get in  the google Dev Tools is: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`
Could someone please explain the error, and how to fix it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `Math.pow(10,decimals)`?

You can't just mash together bits of code and expect it to work. When you write `1e+decimals`, you might *think* that it will understand "stick them together like `1e5` and make it work", but it won't because it means... well, nothing really. `1e` alone is not a valid number, which is why you get the error.

Comment: I'm not trying to do `Math.pow()`, I'm trying to add the zeroes, but your suggestion might work.

Comment: @wyatt I'd also like to point out that `*` happens before `+`... `3 * 4+5` is `17`, not `27`, even with the spaces around the `*`.

Comment: The e+ meant to add that many zeroes, the + isn't a mathematical operator.

Answer (score 1):

`1e` is illegal. You may want to do `1e1`, `1e2`, ... `(n)e(m)`. Two numbers are required around `e`.

You also may try `Math.pow(10, decimals)` or [`10 ** decimals`](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/ebe0f4d2d267370be882) (unfortunately the latter is not supported on major browsers yet).

Comment: I'm not trying to exponent it, I'm attemting to add the zeros of decimals to the variable random, that's what `e+` does.

Comment: `1e+3` works as intended anyway, but this syntax does not allow variables in it. I think `Math.pow(10, 3)` does the same thing.

Comment: 'e+' is not an operator, '1e+3' is just another way to represent a number, same as '1000' - you can't replace parts of it with variable names.